# How to fix iPhone screen width using 4 inch storyboard using auto layout?

Tags: storyboard, autolayout, width, iphone-5

I am new to auto layout. I am using iPhone 4 inch storyboard. Within a view container I have 4 buttons. It is working good in iPhone 5 but when it is running in iPhone 6 and 6+ there is some space at right side. View size is fixed using following code but not 4 buttons.

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    CGRect bounds = self.view.bounds;
    self.contentView.frame = bounds;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (void) viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    self.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    NSDictionary *bindings = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(self.view);
    NSString *formatTemplate = @"%@:|[self.view]|";
    for (NSString * axis in @[@"H",@"V"]) {
        NSString * format = [NSString stringWithFormat:formatTemplate,axis];
        NSArray * constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:format options:0 metrics:nil views:bindings];
        [self.view.superview addConstraints:constraints];
    }

}
```

[I getting reference from here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29205612/programmatically-resize-custom-uiview-from-xib)